# Fatfree Templating error in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, fat-free-framework

I want to make a dynamic page which call ajax when link is clicked and this is my code

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: BASE + '/ui/' + pageStates[state],
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(res){
            $('#main__window').append(res);
        }
    });
});
```

URL link which I fired contains fatfree templating like **{{@BASE}}**, as you can see below

```
<a data-item-image='{{@BASE}}/ui/images/item_hariette.jpg' </a>
```

It's not decoded and I got this error in console

[image]

Thank you..

Comment: Is that <a> element coming from a variable or is inside a view which is loaded dynamically by your controller?

Comment: it's inside my view which loaded dynamically

Comment: Is it a `View` or a `Template` based view? `View` doesn't process non-PHP code.

Comment: It's a `Template`  based View

Comment: can you post the actual html?

Comment: @GeoffreyMureithi which HTML?? All of them??

Comment: `{{ @base }}` is invalid url you need full url which `@base` does not send so you get 404 error which is correct. example in controller `$f3->get('SCHEME').'://'.$f3->get('HOST').$f3->get('BASE'); and set it to all views like function afterroute($f3) { $home_url = $this->home_url; $f3->set('home_url',$home_url); }`

Comment: yeah post sample code link so we can help you better.